# Objective C: Memory Allocation on stack vs. heap

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I am somewhat confused about when things are allocated on the heap (and I need to release them) and when they are allocated on the stack (and I don't need to relese them).

Is there a rule of thumb?

I think in C++ the rule of thumb is that if you use the `new` keyword they are on the heap.  What is the rule with objective c?  How can I tell when something is allocated on the stack?

Will this line of code be allocated on the stack?

```
NSString *user = @"DEFAULT";
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In Objective-C, it's easy: all objects are allocated on the heap.

The rule is, if you call a method with `alloc` or `new` or `copy` in the name (or you call `retain`), you own that object, and you must release it at some point later when you are done with it. There has been plenty written on the subject.

The example you give is a special case: that's a static string, I believe it is actually located in the program's data segment (on the heap), but it's static so you don't need to worry about releasing it.

Comment: I think that `retain` should also be in the list.

Comment: [Keep in mind](https://www.solstice.com/blog/blocks-and-memory-management-stack-vs-heap) that blocks are allocated on the stack by default.

Answer (score 38):

Objective-C is easy in this regard.

### All Objective-C Objects Are Always Allocated On The Heap.

Or, at the least, should be treated as if they are on the heap.

For:

```
NSString *user = @"DEFAULT";
```

The string object is not technically in the heap, but might as well be.  Namely, it is generated by the compiler and is a part of your app's binary.  It doesn't need to be retained and released because the class (`NSCFConstantString`, IIRC) overrides retain/release/autorelease to effectively do nothing.

As for when you do and don't release objects, you should read (and re-read) the [Objective-C memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

(There is one other exception, but it is a rather esoteric detail;   blocks start on the stack and you can Block_copy() them to the heap.  Blocks also happen to be Objective-C objects, but that is rarely exposed in use.)

Comment: Upvoting because of the blocks exception, you should make a copy when you expect the block to be used after destruction of the scope within which it was declared. Copying moves a block to the heap.

Answer (score 1):

There are no stack allocations of objects in Objective-C (Blocks are a different case that I'm not going to get into here)

```
NSString *user = @"DEFAULT";
```

That allocates a NSConstantString object in constant memory, not on the stack.

Comment: There is no such thing as "constant memory", really, though it is an accurate description.  It is really mmap'd readonly memory sourced from a mach-o file on disk (or the dyld shared cache).

Comment: I meant static memory, embedded in the binary. Misspoke :)

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C (and many other languages), an object is simply a contiguous blob of memory with a particular layout. Objects are usually created on the heap. The storage for the object pointer variable itself is on the stack
but the object it points to is in the heap.