# Objective-C NSString Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I have global stings as such:

```
NSString *test = nil;
NSString *test1 = nil;
```

Do I need to alloc with anything? I do change the String value constantly throughout the program, and i'm getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error with segmented control that kills the program.

Any suggestions?

```
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00db6be9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f0b5c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00db86fb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d28366 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00d27f22 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   tipApp                              0x00005f69 -[tipAppViewController exact] + 54
    6   tipApp                              0x00004907 -[tipAppViewController segmentedControlIndexChanged] + 129
    7   UIKit                               0x002bfa6e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    8   UIKit                               0x0034e1b5 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    9   UIKit                               0x00350647 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    10  UIKit                               0x0034e16c -[UIControl sendActionsForControlEvents:] + 49
    11  UIKit                               0x0038d6b2 -[UISegmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:] + 574
    12  UIKit                               0x0039217e -[UISegmentedControl touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 971
    13  UIKit                               0x002e4025 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 395
    14  UIKit                               0x002c537a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    15  UIKit                               0x002ca732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x016eca36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00d98064 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf86f7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf5983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf5240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf5161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x016eb268 GSEventRunModal + 217
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x016eb32d GSEventRun + 115
    24  UIKit                               0x002ce42e UIApplicationMain + 1160
    25  tipApp                              0x00001a8c main + 102
    26  tipApp                              0x00001a1d start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

- Note this only happens when I start the program out, all strings are nil, and I hit all buttons on the segemented control

I'm just not sure exactly what is going on here

Comment: How do you change the String value?

Comment: test = @"Hello"; or whatever I put in their

Comment: Are you using setTitle:forSegmentAtIndex: and passing your global string in?

Comment: What are you doing in -[tipAppViewController exact]

Comment: Thanks, problem found.  Some issue when comparing strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to retain that strings and release every time you reassign new value. It doesn't matter whether it is static variable or ivar. The same memory rules are applied:

```
[test release];
test = [@"new_value" retain];
```

Comment: So I need to release it first, just like the statement above everytime I change the value

Comment: Yep, otherwise you'll have a leak

Comment: test = [test stringByAppendingString:@"1"];

Comment: what about a statement like that?

Comment: For this case use: test = [[[test autorelease] stringByAppendingString:@"1"] retain];

Comment: Or if you want to change, then it's maybe better to use NSMutableString. Then you should initialize it only once with [[NSMutableString alloc] init]

Comment: Uh, no -- There's no reason to retain a constant NSString. ( See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326965/objective-c-memory-allocation-on-stack-vs-heap )

Comment: @Dre Constant strings have infinite retain count, but what if this is not constant like this: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.2f", totalSplit] ? I used constant just for the sake of example

Comment: Thanks, guys.  I found the problem, and I learned a lot about string properties as well.